# while adding prefix to specif files using batch file it adds prefix two time for first file because of bracket '[]'

Tags: batch-file, prefix, batch-rename

i'm trying to add prefix to all files in cur dir and sub dir and i'm succeed in this using following code:

```
@echo off
pushd "D:\z.Temp\Test\"
for /r %%j in (*) do (
   rename "%%j" "[nilesh.uk.to]-%%~nxj"
)
popd
```

But When I Try To Add Prefix For Perticular File Types Such As:

```
@echo off
pushd "D:\z.Temp\Test\"
for /r %%j in (*.html *.js) do (
   rename "%%j" "[nilesh.uk.to]-%%~nxj"
)
popd
```

the it works but it gives me output such as:

```
demo1.html  -->  [nilesh.uk.to]-[nilesh.uk.to]-demo1.html
demo2.html  -->  [nilesh.uk.to]-demo2.html
demo3.html  -->  [nilesh.uk.to]-demo3.html

demo1.js  -->  [nilesh.uk.to]-[nilesh.uk.to]-demo1.js
demo2.js  -->  [nilesh.uk.to]-demo2.js
demo3.js  -->  [nilesh.uk.to]-demo3.js
```

**Here Each first file adding prefix two time**

And If I Remove [] from nilesh.uk.to then it works perfectly but i want prefix as [nilesh.uk.to]
please frendz tell me what to do....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that the renamed files can be found and renamed a second time.

Add an `ECHO rename "%%j" "[nilesh.uk.to]-%%~nxj"` to your code and you will see something like

> rename "C:\temp\bracket\demo1.txt" "[nilesh.uk.to]-demo1.txt" rename
>   "C:\temp\bracket\demo2.txt" "[nilesh.uk.to]-demo2.txt" rename
>   "C:\temp\bracket\demo3.txt" "[nilesh.uk.to]-demo3.txt" rename
>   "C:\temp\bracket[nilesh.uk.to]-demo1.txt"
>   "[nilesh.uk.to]-[nilesh.uk.to]-demo1.txt"

So you need to force the `FOR` loop to take each file only once.

You could change it to

```
for /F "delims=" %%j in ('dir /s /b *.html') do (
....
```

This works, as the `dir /s /b *.html` will be completly executed before the first rename command will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know but I will take a guess. I have some reason to believe it's a good guess. Remove the brackets (the ()) brackets and put commands on one line.

If you do that and the script still doesn't work I'll look at it closely.

Comment: Without testing it, I can say that the `()` aren't the problem